# See If int[][] Contains Specific Values

Tags: java

I have two integer values 'a' and 'b'

I also have a int[][] named 'keys'. It contains number values such as { 0, 1 } and  { 1, 2 }

How would I go about seeing if 'keys' contains the combination of a,b?

What I have tried so far:

```
if (keys.contains({a, b}){
    break;
}
```

This above gives me an illegal start of expression error at the {a,b}

Comment: does array have `contains` method?

Comment: @Deadpool hmm I don't believe so.. so creating a contains method may be needed?

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest to convert `int[][]` to `List<List<Integer>>` then you can use the `contains` method to check the combinations

```
int[][] arr = {{1,2},{3,4}};

    List<Integer> check = Arrays.asList(1,2);

    List<List<Integer>> keys = Arrays.stream(arr)
                               .map(i->Arrays.stream(i).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());  //[[1, 2], [3, 4]]

    System.out.println(keys.contains(check));     //true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean contains(int a, int b, int[][] keys)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
    {
        if (keys[i][0] == a && keys[i][1] == b)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your array is 2*2 you can do this to check for matches.

```
        int a[][] = new int[100][100];
        int keyToCompare = 10;
        int valueToCompare = 20;
        for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
            if(a[i][0] == keyToCompare && a[i][1] == valueToCompare ){
                  //match found
            }
        }
```